# I want to extend a sonar plugin for PHP codesniffer with modification in the default parameters

Tags: php, plugins, sonarqube

During the test in sonar i just wanna some rules to be changed so i took a sample from

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extend+PHP+coding+rules

and make a rule change in

scopeIndentIncorrect and it works . because they have given parameters which I have changed .

but now I want to change the

FunctionCallSignatureIndent
and want to pass a parameters for that

every result I made resulted in creating a new plugin so is there any other way to do it ?

```
<rule key="PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature.Indent" priority="MAJOR">
<category name="Maintainability"/>
<name>CustomFunctionCallSignatureIndent</name>
<configKey>FUNCTION_CALL_SIGNATURE_INDENT</configKey>
<description><![CDATA[Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected %s spaces but found %s]]></description>
<param>
  <key>indent</key>
  <description>The number of spaces code should be indented.</description>
  <defaultValue>4</defaultValue>
</param>
```

This is the entry I made in rules.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to write a Sonar plugin for that. You just have to:

1. Make your changes in FunctionCallSignatureIndent
2. Add a new rule like explained in http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extend+PHP+coding+rules
3. For this new rule, add a "" tag like you can see in the PHPMD example of http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extend+PHP+coding+rules

And then, after restarting Sonar, you should be able to customize this rule in Sonar Web UI.

Comment: hey Fabrice Thanks for reply,  Let me Update my question so you can get what i wanna say. after making this changes I am able to update the pamameter values in profile editor but no any effect on code violation is there after making rebuild of project.

Comment: Have you made the changes in the code of the PHP Sniff itself? (in PHPCodeSniffer install)

Comment: no only change I made is added a parameter in extension file . suggest me if any changes have to be made.

Comment: Yes, you obviously have to modify the source code of PHPCodeSniffer if you want to add a parameter that does not exist. The XML file that you modified is just the bridge between Sonar and PHPCodeSniffer: it tells Sonar that the "PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature.Indent" has a paramater. But if the actual PHPCodeSniffer checker does not have this parameter, this is actually useless.

Comment: Okay, I just got I was just forgot the Initial step. Thanks for your Help.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam the links you provided are no longer persist.
Do you have updated URL's for the same. i am facing the same issues for SonarQube 5.0 with PHP Plugin ver 2.0 greater

Comment: As mention on http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin, the PHP plugin does not rely anymore on external tools so these question and answer are no more valid.